# why bootstrap panel toggle is not working in reactjs build version?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am able to add bootstrap panel toggle in my reactjs development. but when i am deploying react build code this panel is not expanding.
and i know why it is not working in build code because of i am using `href="#panl"`. 
So how can i fix this issue?

```
render() {
    return <div>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panl">Testing</a>
        <div className="panel-collapse collapse section-two" id="pan1">
            <h1>Here is contant of the panel</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may not have installed bootstrap correctly.
run these commands to install it.

```
npm uninstall --save bootstrap
npm install --save bootstrap
```

Comment: i am using cdn not bootstrap package

Comment: so why don't you install it completely?

Comment: that also installed

Comment: that may cause confilicts